# why im getting this error Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, vue.js

my code works perfectly but i still didnt manage to find out why am i getting this error message
i looked it up and it seems that im missing.

And another problem that im having is that when you clcik add button to add a cuecard(a question ) the Select option on the CueCard doesnt show the "Select Color" option it only shows the select with no text
[image]

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
    
    que: '',
    queS: [],
    inputCls: 'inputbox',

    bgColour: 'white',
    classes: ['Select Color', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Green','Orange','Gray','Magenta','Cyan'
    ],

     

    
    };
  },
   watch: {
    que(value) {
      if(value.length > 2) {
        this.showIcon = true;
      }
      else {
        this.showIcon = false;
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {


     addqueS() {
      this.inputCls = 'inputbox';
      this.queS.unshift(
        {
          task: this.que,
          completed: false
        }
      );
      this.que = '';
      setTimeout(() => {
       
      }, 1000);
    },
   
    deleteque(index) {
      this.queS.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
 
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');



a {
  text-decoration: none;
}



.pol, .section {
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
   
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 40px auto;
}
.container h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1em;
}

.pol input {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 30px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #00A2DF;
 
}
.pol .addBtn {
 
  border-radius: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.pol.addBtn i {
 
  flex: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.inputbox {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right center;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.extend {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.queS {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.queS li {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.Blue {
  background: blue; 
}

.Red {
  background: red;
}

.Green {
  background: green;
}
.Orange {
  background: orange;
}
.Gray {
  background: gray; 
}



.Magenta {
  background: magenta;
}
.Cyan {
  background: cyan;
}

/* Add task transition */
.list-enter-active, .list-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.list-enter, .list-leave-to /* .list-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
.list-move { 
  transition: transform .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container" id="demo">
  <h1>CueCards</h1>
  <div class="pol">
    <input type="text" v-model="que" :class="inputCls" autofocus>
    <span class="addBtn">
     
        <button @click="inputCls='inputbox extend'" 
        class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full" 
        v-if="!showIcon">Add Cue</button>
        <button @click="addqueS" 
        class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full"
         v-else>Add</button>
      
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <ul class="queS" v-if="queS.length > 0">
      <transition-group name="list">
        <li :class="item.bgColour" v-for="(item, index) in queS" :key="index">
          <span>{{ item.task }}</span>
          
         
          <span>
           

       

            <button @click="deleteque(index)" 
            class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full">Delete</button>

            <select class="bg-gray-500" v-model="item.bgColour">
   <option  v-for="myClass in classes" :value="myClass">{{ myClass }}
    
  </option>
</select>

          </span>
        </li>
        
        
      </transition-group>
    </ul>
    <h3 v-else>no CueCards to be shown.</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add key prop in this tag

```
 <option  v-for="myClass in classes" :value="myClass">{{ myClass }}
    
  </option>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

Add unique id field in `:key""`

```
<option v-for="(myClass, idx) in classes" :value="myClass" v-bind:key="idx">
 {{ myClass }}
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems key prop is missing here

```
 <option  v-for="myClass in classes" :value="myClass">{{ myClass }}
    
  </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have another v-for directive and you didn't define the key

```
<option  v-for="myClass in classes" :value="myClass">{{ myClass }}</option>
```

it should be like this

```
<option  v-for="( myClass, i ) in classes" :key="i" :value="myClass">{{ myClass }}</option>
```